Is there a way of ingesting data into Workiva from a graph database?
Is there a simple way of ingesting data into Workiva straight from a graph database? This could be from a platform like Stardog or similar.
A workaround I've found is using HTTP requests to query data from the Stardog SPARQL endpoint through the HTTP API, transforming the data if needed so it's compatible with workiva (json for example) and then using the HTTP integration feature to make requests to the Stardog SPARQL endpoint. Would this be feasible?
Thanks in advance.
